# Check logs with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark and I'm trying to develop a python script that reads a csv file with some logs:

```
userId,timestamp,ip,event
13,2016-12-29 16:53:44,86.20.90.121,login
43,2016-12-29 16:53:44,106.9.38.79,login
66,2016-12-29 16:53:44,204.102.78.108,logoff
101,2016-12-29 16:53:44,14.139.102.226,login
91,2016-12-29 16:53:44,23.195.2.174,logoff
```

And checks if a user had some strange behaviors, for example if he has done two consecutive 'login' without doing 'logoff'. I've loaded the csv as a Spark dataFrame and I wanted to compare the log rows of a single user, ordered by timestamp and checking if two consecutive events are of the same type (login - login , logoff - logoff). I'm searching for doing it in a 'map-reduce' way, but at the moment I can't figure out how to use a reduce function that compares consecutive rows. 
The code I've written works, but the performance are very bad.

```
sc = SparkContext("local","Data Check")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

LOG_FILE_PATH = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/flume/events/*"
RESULTS_FILE_PATH = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/spark/script_results/prova/bad_users.csv"
N_USERS = 10*1000

dataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load(LOG_FILE_PATH)
dataFrame = dataFrame.selectExpr("C0 as userID","C1 as timestamp","C2 as ip","C3 as event")

wrongUsers = []

for i in range(0,N_USERS):

    userDataFrame = dataFrame.where(dataFrame['userId'] == i)
    userDataFrame = userDataFrame.sort('timestamp')

    prevEvent = ''

    for row in userDataFrame.rdd.collect():

        currEvent = row[3]
        if(prevEvent == currEvent):
            wrongUsers.append(row[0])

        prevEvent = currEvent

badUsers = sqlContext.createDataFrame(wrongUsers)
badUsers.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(RESULTS_FILE_PATH)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (not related but still), be sure that the number of entries per user is not that big because that `collect` in `for row in userDataFrame.rdd.collect():` is dangerous.

Second, you don't need to leave the `DataFrame` area here to use classical Python, just stick to Spark.

Now, your problem. It's basically "for each line I want to know something from the previous line": that belongs to the concept of `Window` functions and to be precise the `lag` function. Here are two interesting articles about Window functions in Spark: one from [Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) with code in Python and one from [Xinh](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.fr/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html) with (I think easier to understand) examples in Scala.

I have a solution in Scala, but I think you'll pull it off translating it in Python:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag

import sqlContext.implicits._

val LOG_FILE_PATH = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/flume/events/*"
val RESULTS_FILE_PATH = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/spark/script_results/prova/bad_users.csv"

val data = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true") // use the header from your csv
  .load(LOG_FILE_PATH)

val wSpec = Window.partitionBy("userId").orderBy("timestamp")

val badUsers = data
  .withColumn("previousEvent", lag($"event", 1).over(wSpec))
  .filter($"previousEvent" === $"event")
  .select("userId")
  .distinct

badUsers.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(RESULTS_FILE_PATH)
```

Basically you just retrieve the value from the previous line and compare it to the value on your current line, if it's a match that is a wrong behavior and you keep the `userId`. For the first line in your "block" of lines for each `userId`, the previous value will be `null`: when comparing with the current value, the boolean expression will be `false` so no problem here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly the solution I was searching for. It is possible also to pass a function to the filter method? Because I also have to do some stuff with the ip

Comment: Yes of course you can add something to the filter. Just remember that if you can't express what you want your function to do with simple comparisons or with Spark's Column-based [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#module-pyspark.sql.functions), you'll need to use `UDF`s, see that [page](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-udfs.html) for more info.